# How to perform calculation on the current row in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to calculate the multiplication of quantity and rate that is to be displayed on amount box..My problem is it the multiplication result is displayed on all the row of the table..below i attached the screenshot

[image]
html code for first row of the table:

```
 <table class="tb3" name="tb3">
<tr >                       
    <td><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove3'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>
    <td><input  type="text" onchange="fetchdetails(this)" class="Product_Code" name="Prdtcode[]" class="form-control input-xs Product_Code "   required></td>
    <td ><input type="text" class="Product_Name" name="Prdtname[]" class="form-control input-xs"   > </td>
    <td><input  type="text" 
    onkeypress="javascript:doit_onkeypress(event)"  class="Qty" onkeyup="movetoNext(this, 'addMore3')" name="Qty[]"class="form-control input-xs" required ></td>
    <td><input  type="text" class="Rate"  class="form-control input-xs"name="Rate[]" value="" ></td>
    <td><input  type="text" class="Value"  class="form-control input-xs"name="amount[]" value=""  ></td>
</tr>
```

javascript code for dynamic generation of table:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.tb3').on('keydown','input', function (e) {
var keyCode = e.keyCode;
if (keyCode !== 9) return;
var $this = $(this),
    $lastTr = $('tr:last', $('.tb3')),
    $lastTd = $('td:last', $lastTr);
if (($(e.target).closest('td')).is($lastTd)) {
var cloned = $lastTr.clone();
cloned.find('input').val('');

$lastTr.after(cloned);
}

});
```

javascript code for calculation:

```
<script >
    $(document).on('keydown','input', function ()  {


    $('.Qty').on("input change",function(){
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var price = 0;
        var total = 0;

        $('.tb3').each(function() {

            var qty = $($row).closest('tr').find('.Qty').val();
             var rate = $($row).closest('tr').find('.Rate').val();
             var price =  qty * rate;
               $(this).find('.Value').val(price);
            total += parseFloat(price);
              });
         $('#TieTotal').val(total.toFixed(2));
    });

    $('.Value').on(function(){
                $('.tb3').each(function() {
             });
        $('#TieTotal').val(total.toFixed(2));
    });
    });
</script>
```

Move to next:

```
function movetoNext(current, nextFieldID) {
if (current.value.length == 1) {
document.getElementById(nextFieldID).focus();
}
}
```

What alteration i have to done in my code...help me

Comment: Hello, can you also paste `doit_onkeypress` and `movetoNext` functions?

Comment: done..check it above

Comment: Which element has `.tb3` ? I see mutlipe class attributes for same element. Add space before `name` attribute

Comment: tb3 is name of the table

Comment: Because the following statement:

 $(this).find('.Value').val(price);
It will update the value to all elements which have class name "Value".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that have got some issues with the approach you have used to loop.

I have changed `$('.tb3')` to be `$('.tb3 tr')`, so it will loop through each row. Then inside the loop I have replaced instances such as `$($row).closest('tr').find('.Qty')` with `$(this).find('.Qty')` because you are already in the row.

See the corrected code below,

```
$(document).on('keydown','input', function ()  {
    $('.Qty').on("input change",function(){

        var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var price = 0;
        var total = 0;

        $('.tb3 tr').each(function() {
             var qty = $(this).find('.Qty').val();
             var rate = $(this).find('.Rate').val();
             var price =  qty * rate;
             $(this).find('.Value').val(price);
             total += parseFloat(price);
        });
         $('#TieTotal').val(total.toFixed(2));
    });

    $('.Value').on(function(){
         $('.tb3').each(function() { });
         $('#TieTotal').val(total.toFixed(2));
    });
 });
```

**Link to fiddle,**

https://jsfiddle.net/anjanasilva/dykm6wau/

Comment: Instead of making a jsfiddle, you can make a Stack Snippet. This will display on this page, so it's easier to access. It's the `<>` button in the editing toolbar, iirc.

Comment: sir one more help @ Anjana silva

Comment: What's that @laavanyadharani ?

Comment: sir i want to calculate the sum of amount again when the row is removed..can you please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53096329/how-to-change-calculation-when-the-row-is-removed-from-a-table/53096521#53096521

Comment: Don't call me sir :D . I will have a look :) @laavanyadharani