# How to change calculation when the row is removed from a table

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

My problem is the calculations are working fine but when the row is removed the calculations are not updating according to that after creating a new row and after performing calculation only the values are updating..please help me to rectify this problem.

```
$(document).on('change', 'tr td:nth-child(6), tr td:nth-child(5), tr td:nth-child(4)', .
    'remove3'
    function() {
        var total = 0;
        var sqty = 0;
        var tr = $(this).parent();
        var qty = tr.find('td:nth-child(4)').find('input').val();
        var rate = tr.find('td:nth-child(5)').find('input').val();
        var amount = qty * rate;
        tr.find('td:nth-child(6)').find('input').val(amount);

        var tbody = tr.parent();

        $(tbody).find('tr').each(function() {
            total += Number($(this).find('td:nth-child(6)').find('input').val());
            sqty += Number($(this).find('td:nth-child(4)').find('input').val());
        });

        $('#TieTotal').val(total);
        $('#SQty').val(sqty);
        $('#Grandtot').val(total);
    })
```

Script to create a next row automatically:

```
$('.tb3').on('keydown', 'input', function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if (keyCode !== 9) return;
    var $this = $(this),
        $lastTr = $('tr:last', $('.tb3')),
        $lastTd = $('td:last', $lastTr);
    if (($(e.target).closest('td')).is($lastTd)) {
        var cloned = $lastTr.clone();
        cloned.find('input').val('');

        $lastTr.after(cloned);
    }
});
```

Script to delete row:

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove3', function() {
    var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
    if (trIndex > 0) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    } else {
        alert("Sorry!! Can't remove first row!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Put the code by which you are calculating inside a function and on the row delete call the same function again. It will manage everything.

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle or working snippet of your code.

Comment: just convert your calculation parts into a function then whenever you add new row just called that function.

Comment: I am creating a new row when the user hits a tab on the last column of the row so i can't make my calculation on a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     $(document).on('change', 'tr td:nth-child(6), tr td:nth-child(5), tr td:nth-child(4)', .
            'remove3'
            function() {
                var total = 0;
                var sqty = 0;
                var tr = $(this).parent();
                var qty = tr.find('td:nth-child(4)').find('input').val();
                var rate = tr.find('td:nth-child(5)').find('input').val();
                var amount = qty * rate;
                tr.find('td:nth-child(6)').find('input').val(amount);

                var tbody = tr.parent();

                $(tbody).find('tr').each(function() {
                    total += Number($(this).find('td:nth-child(6)').find('input').val());
                    sqty += Number($(this).find('td:nth-child(4)').find('input').val());
                });

                $('#TieTotal').val(total);
                $('#SQty').val(sqty);
                $('#Grandtot').val(total);
            })

    Script to create a next row automatically:

        $('.tb3').on('keydown', 'input', function(e) {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode;
            if (keyCode !== 9) return;
            var $this = $(this),
                $lastTr = $('tr:last', $('.tb3')),
                $lastTd = $('td:last', $lastTr);
            if (($(e.target).closest('td')).is($lastTd)) {
                var cloned = $lastTr.clone();
                cloned.find('input').val('');

                $lastTr.after(cloned);
            }
        });

    Script to delete row:

        $(document).on('click', '.remove3', function() {
            var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
            if (trIndex > 0) {
                $(this).closest("tr").remove();
 $('.Qty').trigger('change');
            } else {
                alert("Sorry!! Can't remove first row!");
            }
        });
```

Comment: May I know why you unaccepted my answer and accepted your own answer?

Comment: Your answer does not work exactly for me.. I made some changes in my code according to your answer...

Comment: That's ok. You accepted my answer before and then you suddenly decided to accept your own answer. Anyway, what's important is your question getting answered :) Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine you have an HTML like (could be a dynamically drawn HTML).

```
<tr>
  <td><input class="Qty" type="text" value="2"/></td>
  <td><input class="Rate" type="text" value="200"/></td>
  <td><input class="Value" type="text"/></td>
  <td><button type="button" class="remove3">X</button></td>
</tr>
```

Also, let's say you have changed the approach to update the total to be like this, (which is inside document ready). This is a sample code, your actual code may vary. All you need to do is keep the triggering `on("keyup change")` (or as however you like) inside the `document.ready()`.

```
$('.Qty').on("keyup change",function(){         
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var price = 0;
    var total = 0;

    $('.tb3 tr').each(function() {
         var qty = $(this).find('.Qty').val();
         var rate = $(this).find('.Rate').val();             
         var price =  qty * rate;             
         $(this).find('.Value').val(price);
         total += parseFloat(price);
    });
     $('#TieTotal').val(total.toFixed(2));
});
```

Now, when each time you press the button which has class `.remove3` you are correct in terms of removing the row. In the same block you can easilty update the total by triggering the `change()` event of element which has the class `.Qty`. (That's how the total is updated in the first place) See below,

```
$('.remove3').click(function ()  {
    var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
  if (trIndex > 0) {
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
      $('.Qty').trigger('change');
  } else {
      alert("Sorry!! Can't remove first row!");
    }      
});
```

Fiddle,
https://jsfiddle.net/anjanasilva/dykm6wau/

I hope this helps.
Cheers!

Comment: @laavanyadharani Did you find this useful?

Comment: @laavanyadharani No worries :) I am glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Update this line:

```
$(document).on('change', 'tr td:nth-child(6), tr td:nth-child(5), tr td:nth-child(4), .remove3' function(){
```

i think class '.remove3' not added properly with selectors list.

Comment: done..but the value is not updating when the row is removed

Comment: first, check change event fire for class `remove3` hit, then check other parts to work properly for required action.

Comment: can't understand

Comment: you need to move calculation part in a separate method so can be called in create/remove row methods OR you need to do calculation part again in remove row action

Comment: provide jsfiddle or wokring code snippet, so can be checked the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182918/discussion-between-laavanya-dharani-and-manoj-singh).